# jquery CALLING TO Services! Services.invoke

Tags: ajax, entity-framework, jquery, asp.net-ajax

This a service function "GetTaskProgress":

```
[WebMethod]
public IList<OrderViewDTO> GetTaskProgress(DateTime xDATEx)
{
    try
    {
        return new OrderDataRepository()
            .GetAllOrderData()
            .Where(x => x.POD_DATE == xDATEx)
            .GroupBy(o => o.User)
            .Select(g => new OrderViewDTO
            {
                DriverId = g.Key.Id,
                PdriverName = g.Key.Name,
                OrderCount = g.Count(),
                OrderCountWhereNameIsNotNull = g.Count(o => o.RECEIVE_NAME != null)
            })
            .ToList();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw WrapException(e);
    }
}
```

This is the code of the jquery load button:

```
                                        $('#LoadButton').click(function () {
                                            var DateTime = $('#DateInput').val();

                                            if (DateTime == '') 
                                                         {
                                                             alert('PLEASE ENTER DATE');
                                                         } 
                                            else {

                                                    _Services.invoke({
                                                        method: 'GetTaskProgress',
                                                        data: { DateTime: DateTime },

                                                   success: function () {
                                                       alert(DateTime);
```

How do I call GetTaskProgress with a jQuery function that will pass the "date" into `xDATEx`?

at the moment when i click on the button i have the bug **Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: 'xDATEx**

Comment: rory, can you help me please? what have you changed?

Comment: Have you tried `data: { xDATEx: DateTime }`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about `_Services.invoke()` (analogous to `$.ajax()` perhaps?), but you probably need to change your data parameter to match your service method parameter. Try this

```
_Services.invoke({
        method: 'GetTaskProgress',
        data: { xDATEx: DateTime },    
        success: function () {
            alert(DateTime);
        }
    });
```